# Why a Spring Around advice can swallow, or halt the propagation of, an exception thown by the target method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aop, spring-aop

I am studying for the Spring Core certification and I have the following doubt on this question founded on my study material:

> Which of the following statments is NOT true about advice types and
>   exception handling?
>
> - If a **Before** advice throws an exception, the target method will not be called.
> - An **Around** advice can swallow, or halt the propagation of, an exception thown by the target method.
> - An **AfterReturning** advice type can swallow, or halt the propagation of, an exception thown by the target method.

Now I know that the correct answer of the previous question is the last one (I have the answers) but why?

So it ask me what statment is not true so it means that the first 2 statments are true.

I am trying to analyze the previous 3 case doing some concrete example but I am not soure that my reasoning are correct.

1) **BEFORE ADVICE**:

I can have something like this:

```
@Aspect
public class PropertyChangeTracker {
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    @Before(“execution(void check*(*))”)
    public void trackCheck() {
        logger.info(“Property about to check…”);
   }
}
```

So the implemented advice (that create a log row into a .log file) is performed each time that a **checkSomething(oneArgument)** method is performed. If during the execution of this method an exception is thrown the advice is not performed.

I think that this is pretty clear

2) **AROUND ADVICE**, I know that this is the sequence diagram of the **Around advice**

[image]

and I have the following example of this kind of advice:

```
@Around("execution(* com.journaldev.spring.model.Employee.getName())")
public Object employeeAroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint){
    System.out.println("Before invoking getName() method");
    Object value = null;
    try {
        value = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("After invoking getName() method. Return value="+value);
    return value;
}
```

Reading the official documentation I found that:

> **Around advice**: Advice that surrounds a join point such as a method
>   invocation. This is the most powerful kind of advice. Around advice
>   can perform custom behavior before and after the method invocation. It
>   is also responsible for choosing whether to proceed to the join point
>   or to shortcut the advised method execution by returning its own
>   return value or throwing an exception.

So it seems to me that **Around advice** is used to cut the method execution before and after the jointpoint execution. We can use it to control whether the advised method will execute or not. We can also inspect the returned value and change it. This is the most powerful advice and needs to be applied properly.

So in the previous example I think that it is performed twice time: the first one before that the **getName()** method is executed and a second one after that the **getName()** method is executed.

But what exacty does the

```
value = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
```

I think that it is the division point between the execution before and after the joint point, in this case I think that the **proceed()** method say that the **getName()** method have to be performed and that its result is to be putted into the **value** field. Is it right or am I missing something?

So coming back to the original statment I can say that

> An **Around** advice can swallow, or halt the propagation of, an
>   exception thown by the target method.

why can I say that this is true? What exatly means?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So in the previous example I think that it is performed twice time: the first one before that the getName() method is executed and a second one after that the getName() method is executed.

If I understood what you think here, you are wrong. The advice is called only once, and the code in it is responsible for calling the actual advised method `getName()`. That's what `proceedingJoinPoint.proceed()` does.

One typical scenario - you intercept the method call, perform some checks, invoke the method (or not, maybe depending on the result of the checks), and return the result. In the example you posted, `proceed()` is surrounded with `try - catch` block, which means you can catch the exception thrown by the `getName()` and do whatever you want with it. This explains why the second sentence in your question is true.

Comment: Perfect explaination, now it is pretty clear for me :-)

Comment: @PredragMaric What if Employee.getName() is catching exception already and I have some kind of recovery mechanism inside catch block of Employee.getName() ..and we have Around advice with proceed() with try-catch..Where it would be catched first?Will my recovery mechanism get executed inside Employee.getName()'s catch block or it won't?

Comment: @SagarKadu The first catch block will catch it, which is the catch block inside `getName()`. No special rules apply here, all standard rules apply.

Comment: @PredragMaric Thanks..appreciate if you can answer this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57039598/logger-clean-up-using-spring-aop

Answer (score 6):

Using `@Around` is just like writing your own code and calling a method, except that you use `proceedingJoinPoint.proceed()` instead. As with a normal method call, you can choose to not execute it (wrap it in a conditional) or catch errors thrown by it (wrap the call in a try block).

From the [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-around-advice):

> Around advice is declared using the @Around annotation. The first parameter of the advice method must be of type ProceedingJoinPoint. Within the body of the advice, calling proceed() on the ProceedingJoinPoint causes the underlying method to execute. The proceed method may also be called passing in an Object[] - the values in the array will be used as the arguments to the method execution when it proceeds.

So, specifically: `value = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();` causes the underlying method to be called and its return value to be assigned to `value`.

> An Around advice can swallow, or halt the propagation of, an exception thown by the target method.

This happens by doing:

```
try {
   proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
} catch (Throwable e) {
    // ignore or handle
}
```

Comment: So (related to my original example) are you meaning that when I do proceedingJoinPoint.proceed() the employeeAroundAdvice() method is perforemd, if it throws an exception I can catch it and handle or ignore it?

Comment: When you call `proceed()`, the `Employee.getName()` method is invoked, and if you wrap this call in a try-catch, you can handle or ignore it, yes.

Comment: @beerbajay What if `Employee.getName()` is catching exception already and I have some kind of recovery mechanism inside catch block of `Employee.getName()` ..and we have Around advice with `proceed()` with try-catch..Where it would be catched first?Will my recovery mechanism get executed  inside `Employee.getName()`'s catch block or it won't?

Comment: @SagarKadu There's nothing magic happening, so standard rules about exception handling apply. If you have exception handling in `getName()` then these will be invoked normally and only any raised or uncaught exceptions will reach the `@Around` code.

Comment: @beerbajay Thanks..appreciate if you can answer this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57039598/logger-clean-up-using-spring-aop