# Logger clean up Using Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, logging, aop, spring-aop

We're trying to introduce generic logger in our application using Spring AOP for log statements which are under catch block.

Before AOP

```
try
{
\\Business Logic 
}
catch(Exception e){
\\some recovery mechanism that won't be generic across different layers
log.error();//These statements needs to be moved to generic logger
}
```

After going through Spring Docs,I have found this can be done using AfterThrowing advice.
After throwing advice is Advice to be executed if a method exits by throwing an exception.

In order to do this We'll to change our existing exception handling code by re throwing `Exception` inside `catch` block something like this for `AfterThrowing` Advice to work.

After AOP:

```
try
{
\\Business Logic
}
catch(Exception e){
 \\some recovery mechanism that won't be generic across different layers
throw e;
}
```

AOP code:

```
@Aspect
@Sl4j
@Component
public class LoggingAdvice {
    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution (* * com..*(..)", throwing = "e")
    public void myAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Exception e) {    
    log.error("Exception occured",e);
    }
}
```

Do you think is there any better solution than this rather than rethrowing Exception in catch block and propagating it upwards as per call hierarchy?

Note any raised or unchecked exceptions would be catched anyway by AfterThrowing Advice..All i want to do is perform logger clean up by removing `log.error` inside catch block and have it generic using AOP.

Comment: Don't catch... What do you gain if you only rethrow?

Comment: @M.Deinum I can't..because we have different recovery mechanisms spanned across multiple classes..only reason behind re throwing it is to make `AfterThrowing` work and catch exception again in generic AOP code to log it.

Comment: If you only catch and rethrow, there is no sense in doing a catch. It will `@AfterThrowing` doesn't depend on a catch block.

Comment: @M.Deinum agreed `@AfterThrowing` doesn't depend on a catch block but I want my method to exit with `Exception` for `@AfterThrowing` to work so that i can log the stacktrace in AOP code rather than logging it in Business logic

Comment: and how would a catch block with only a `throw e` when doing a `catch (Exception e)` help? It is exactly the same if you leave out the catch... Unless you want to convert to a specialized exception and throw that (but that isn't what is clear in the question). Also if you convert why not make the conversion generic and do the logging there instead of using AOP. (

Comment: @M.Deinum `catch(Exception e){//some recovery mechanism that won't be generic across different layers//  throw e}` thats reason i don't want to leave catch..and as long as it is `Throwable` I would be able do the conversion in AOP(which AOP does internally i believe)..so that I wouldn't lose any valuable stacktrace

Comment: @NathanHughes good point..but as long as I remove it from Business logic and keep it inside AOP,it should not repeat

Comment: If there is more logic in the catch you cannot remove it, unless you make a very smart aspect which does the recovery as well. But that would beat the purpose of the aspect as it would start to contain specific stuff for single usecases. Also please add the fact that you have additional logic in your catch blok to your question, now it looks like only a catch with just a rethrow of the exception.

Comment: If the only purpose of the AOP is to log error messages (without removing the catch block) then IMO it's an overkill. Simply create an utility class with static method(s) and delegate your logging to it to have a central, single implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was discussed here, `@AfterThrowing` is nice for logging exceptions which are actually ***thrown***.

Your case is quite special as you want to log exceptions which are being ***caught/handled***. If you [use full AspectJ](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) instead of Spring AOP for this use case you can use a `handler(*)` pointcut as described with sample code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31093787/1082681). It would enable you to factor out your log statements from your `catch` blocks without the need to escalate (re-throw) exceptions which have already been properly handled, thus changing your logic and making it necessary to catch them somewhere else later.

Answer (score 0):

The better approach is to remove the `catch` blocks as you are going to use `@AfterThrowing` anyway. And implement whatever you want to implement on top that aspect execution.

Comment: I can't remove catch block..please check updated question